# How to change active tab color in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How I can change the color of the active tab?

I mean, this `pink` line, look at the pic.

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Hi if anyone is still having issues with changing the color, following worked for me:

```
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  TabIndicatorProps={{
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "#D97D54"
    }
  }}
>
...
</Tabs>
```

Comment: refer here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11085

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: From MUI v5, this is the better answer imo since the style overrides was altered and the style engine was changed. It worked best for me.

Answer (score 50):

You can try this material UI latest version support TabIndicatorProps through which you can pass style key.

```
<Tabs TabIndicatorProps={{style: {background:'ANY_COLOR'}}}>......
```

Answer (score 24):

Well, you have two options:

You could customize the theme:
http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes

But the easiest way would be using the `inkBarStyle` property.
You can see it in the [docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs)..
Example:

```
<Tabs inkBarStyle={{background: 'blue'}}>...
```

Comment: You my hero! (-: Maybe I'm blind, if watched, but did not see in the documentation....

Comment: How do I find a list of all the options I can change (`background: 'blue'`, `something else: 'some other setting'`, `another thing I'm not aware of`, etc)?

Comment: What I'd really like to do is set the color to be black and the height (horizontal line thickness) to be thicker, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: I asked this as a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401130/how-to-change-active-tab-inkbarstyle-color-and-thickness-in-react-material-ui

Comment: deprecated answer. The newer versions have completely changed everything (and turned simple customizations into a nightmare)

Comment: What property or option in the themes makes this active tab red? Which property should I be looking at because I hate the red. Is it the secondary main color ?

Answer (score 24):

@Risa's solution works just fine and should be the accepted answer. My example of her explanation looks like this:

```
<Tabs
  fullWidth
  centered
  classes={{
    indicator: classes.indicator
  }}>
    <Tab />
    <Tab />
</Tabs>
```

and the styles:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
})
```

Answer (score 14):

try this

```
import { makeStyles} from '@mui/styles';

    const useStyles = makeStyles({
  tabs: {

    "& .MuiTabs-indicator": {
      backgroundColor: "orange",
      height: 3,
    },
    "& .MuiTab-root.Mui-selected": {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
})
```

and then

```
const classes = useStyles();
<Tabs
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    // textColor="secondary"
    // indicatorColor="secondary"
    aria-label="secondary tabs example"
    className={classes.tabs}
    // TabIndicatorProps={{
    //   style: { background: "green", height: 3}
    // }}
  >
  <Tab label={<span className={styles.tabs}>{ABOUT_US}</span>} component={Link} to="/about-us" />
  <Tab label={<span className={styles.tabs}>{ABOUT_HANBANABORINA}</span>} component={Link} to="/about-hanbanaborina" />
  <Tab label={<span className={styles.tabs}>{DOWNLOAD_APPLICATION}</span>} component={Link} to="/download" />
  <Tab label={<span className={styles.tabs}>{HOME}</span>} component={Link} to="/" />
  </Tabs>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this! I had an issue: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76369424/mui-tabs-tabindicator-color-not-taking-from-global-theme` and modifying this: `'& .Mui-selected'` to `'& .MuiTab-root.Mui-selected'` resolved my issue!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution! It's great to hear that modifying the code from '& .Mui-selected' to '& .MuiTab-root.Mui-selected' resolved your issue. It's amazing how small tweaks can make a big difference. Keep up the good work! @RogueGingerz

Answer (score 11):

#### Material UI v5 update

You can use the `sx` prop in Material UI v5 instead of inline styles. To declare a custom color:

```
<Tabs
  {...}
  TabIndicatorProps={{
    sx: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  }}
>
```

Many of the `sx` properties are also [theme aware](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#theme-aware-properties). To use one of the colors from the palette:

```
<Tabs
  {...}
  TabIndicatorProps={{
    sx: {
      backgroundColor: 'secondary.main',
    },
  }}
>
```

Or if you want to change the indicator color globally:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTabs: {
      styleOverrides: {
        indicator: {
          backgroundColor: 'orange',
          height: 3,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 7):

I put here a end of 2019's update because I didn't found my answer here. A lot of answers are depreciated.

The best way to override without having too much pain seems to use the makeStyle and withStyles of material-ui.

Here is an exemple with tabs.

you need to import makeStyles

```
    import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
    import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs'
```

here are my customs classes using makeStyles()

```
     const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
     customOne: {
        padding: '3rem 15rem',
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
     },
     customTwo: {
        padding: '0rem',
        color: '#484848',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
        fontSize: '1rem',
    },
   }))
```

For more overrides you can also create a function that use props using by material ui (root, etc.) using withStyles() :

```
    const TabStyle = withStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
       padding: '1rem 0',
       textTransform: 'none',
       fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
       fontSize: '1.2rem',
       fontFamily: [
           '-apple-system',
           'BlinkMacSystemFont',
           'Roboto',
       ].join(','),
       '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: '#004C9B',
          color: 'white',
          opacity: 1,
       },
      '&$selected': {
          backgroundColor: '#004C9B',
          color: 'white',
          fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
      },
  },
  tab: {
      padding: '0.5rem',
      fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
      fontSize: '2rem',
      backgroundColor: 'grey',
      color: 'black',
      '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          color: 'white',
          opacity: 1,
      },
  },
  selected: {},
  }))((props) => <Tab {...props} />)
```

in my component I define : const classes = useStyles() that permit to change my useStyles props in classes.

I use my custom classes whenever I want like this :
className={classes.customOne}

```
    export default function TabsCustom({ activeTabIndex, onChange, values }) {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0)

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
       setValue(newValue)
  }


    return (
        <div className={classes.customOne}>
            <Tabs
                className={classes.customTwo}
                variant="fullWidth"
                value={activeTabIndex}
                onChange={onChange}
                aria-label="tabs"
            >
                <TabStyle
                    value="updateDate"
                    icon={(<Icon>insert_invitation</Icon>)}
                    label={i18n.perYear}
                />

            </Tabs>
    </div>
   )
 }
```

Hope it help. Personnaly I would have gained a lot of time (and pain) if I had found this explanation.

Answer (score 6):

**Example one:**

Js:

```
<Tabs indicatorColor="primary" classes={{ indicator: classes.indicator }}>
```

style:

```
indicator:{
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    }
```

**Example two:**

```
<Tabs TabIndicatorProps={{style: {background:'green'}}} >
```

Answer (score 6):

Whoever is using Mui v5+, and wants to config this as components styles Override with custom theme:

```
MuiTab: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      '&.Mui-selected': {
        color: theme.menuSelected
      }
    }
  }
},
MuiTabs: {
  styleOverrides: {
    indicator: {
      backgroundColor: theme.menuSelected
    }
  }
}
```

MuiTab refers to the to `<Tab />` component and MuiTabs to `<Tabs />`.

Answer (score 4):

For material-ui version 1.0.0-beta.36, the following worked for me:

```
<Tabs indicatorColor={'HEX_COLOR'}>
```

*inkBarStyle* must've been deprecated/replaced by *indicatorColor* in v1.0

EDIT: Link to v1.0 docs: https://material-ui-next.com/api/tabs/

EDIT: Following the stable release of v1.0, it appears the previous solution no longer works.

Here are remaining solutions:

1. Use a classes override for the `indicator` class. [Link to docs on overrides.](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes) [Link to docs Tab component with CSS API classes at bottom.](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/)
2. Configure your theme palette to use your desired color via the `primary` or `secondary` color intentions. You may then specify your desired `primary` or `secondary` color to be used with the `indicatorColor` attribute mentioned above. [Link to Docs.](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#palette)

Classes overrides may be the easier option. You need to use the `withStyles` component in order to inject your custom style classes. The reason being that the library's styling will override your classes or styled-components. The docs linked above provide a great example.

Comment: Trying in v1 and getting this: `Failed prop type: Invalid prop indicatorColor of value #FFF supplied to Tab, expected one of ["secondary","primary"]`

Comment: @dauffret Thanks for your response. I did check the docs for the updated stable v1.0 and have updated my comment above. Let me know if you have any remaining questions. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: As this question is 2 years old as was most likely intended for v 0.X, I've asked the question again for v1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533704/how-to-implement-custom-tab-indicator-color-in-material-ui-v1/50533705

Answer (score 4):

Met this question just, hope help your guys;

```
          <Tabs classes={{ indicator: `your classes like underline` }} >
            <Tab
              classes={{ selected: `your classes like underline` }}
            />
            <Tab
              classes={{ selected: classes.selectedTab }}
            />
          </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can now use the TabIndicatorProps to style the active indicator with the current version of MUI (4.10.02). Docs available [here](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/).

There are 2 ways to do this:

**METHOD 1: *using style***

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Tabs, Tab, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const TabsIndicator = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <Tabs
         value={value}
         onChange={handleChange}
         TabIndicatorProps={{
           style: { background: "cyan", height: "10px", top: "35px" }
         }}
       >
         <Tab label="TEST1" value={0} />
         <Tab label="TEST2" value={1} />
         <Tab label="TEST3" value={2} />
         <Tab label="TEST4" value={3} />
       </Tabs>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default TabsIndicator;
```

**Method 2: *using classes***

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Tabs, Tab, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    height: "10px",
    top: "45px"
  }
}));

const TabsIndicator = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          TabIndicatorProps={{ className: classes.indicator }}
        >
          <Tab label="TEST1" value={0} />
          <Tab label="TEST2" value={1} />
          <Tab label="TEST3" value={2} />
          <Tab label="TEST4" value={3} />
        </Tabs>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default TabsIndicator;
```

You can also check out my [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-tabs-sbwch?file=/src/pages/sections/Tabs01indicator.js:0-2178). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

**MUI v5.2.0**

Since the props of the `Tabs` component are also available on `TabList` we can use `TabIndicatorProps` with the `TabList` and `sx` prop for styling

```
<TabList TabIndicatorProps={{ sx: { backgroundColor: 'green'} }} >
```

- The `sx` prop is a shortcut for defining a custom style that has access to the theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indicatorColor` and `textColor` properties of `Tabs` if you want to switch colors from Material UI.

```
<Tabs
   value={selectedTab}
   indicatorColor="secondary"
   textColor="secondary"
   className="w-full h-64"
>
 ...
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the new version, most of those above won't work. To customize the colors, visit the documentation

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  createTheme,
  ThemeProvider
} from '@mui/material/styles';
import {
  purple
} from '@mui/material/colors';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // Purple and green play nicely together.
      main: purple[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      // This is green.A700 as hex.
      main: '#11cb5f',
    },
  },
});

export default function Palette() {
  return ( <
    ThemeProvider theme = {
      theme
    } >
    <
    Button > Primary < /Button> <
    Button color = "secondary" > Secondary < /Button> <
    /ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a fairly old question, it still getting some attention and for those of us who are using multiple and heavily customized themes, this is a hassle. I have a better solution that will allow you to customize it in different colors according to the theme

First, create a class you can hook to by adding it to the Tabs component this way

```
<Tabs
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   value={this.state.slideIndex}
   className="dashboard-tabs"> //this is what you need
       <Tab label="Main" value={0}/>
       <Tab label="Analytics" value={1}/>
       <Tab label="Live Widgets" value={2}/>
</Tabs>
```

Keep in mind, my tabs and your tabs may be different so pay attention to only the className line. You can name it whatever you want. 1. If you want to have different tabs having a different underline, name it something meaningful like dashboard-tabs if the tabs are in the dashboard or quickpanel-tabs if they are part of a quickpanel, etc. 2. if your tabs will be essentially the same, name it more globally like material-tabs and now you can use that class anywhere and your css will work without having to create this again.

Now, use this class as a hook class and use specificity to reach the underline, like this

```
.dashboard-tabs > div{
    background-color: #333 !important;
}
.dashboard-tabs > div:nth-child(2) > div{
    background-color: #ddd !important;
}
```

Don't worry about the !important. The tabboo that using !important is bad, is all nothing but a big tabboo. You'll be fine.

Here is a SCSS sample

```
.dashboard-tabs{
    > div{
        background-color: $bg-color-meddark !important;
        &:nth-child(2){
            > div{
                background-color: $brand-info !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution would be extremely helpful if you were using multiple themes because, (assuming you are theming correctly), you should have a dynamic theme class being appended above in your code somewhere that changes your UI from one color to the next. So, say you have 2 themes. 1 is light and uses the theme class `light-theme` and 2 is a dark theme and uses the `dark-theme` class

Now, you can do this as follows:

```
.light-theme .dashboard-tabs > div{
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
.light-theme .dashboard-tabs > div:nth-child(2) > div{
    background-color: #333 !important;
}
.dark-theme .dashboard-tabs > div{
    background-color: #333 !important;
}
.dark-theme .dashboard-tabs > div:nth-child(2) > div{
    background-color: #ddd !important;
}
```

Makes sense?

Why am I against the InkBarStyle solution? Because you'd be replacing one background color for another and still not able to change it across themes

Good luck everyone!

Comment: for this one, i recommend that you use:
.tabs > div:nth-child(1){}
in order to change only the tab color and not all the divs inside your tab (:

Comment: but, using !important is actually a bad practice, and it should be taboo...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a theme template to use in your projects:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

let _colors = require('material-ui/styles/colors');
let _colorManipulator = require('material-ui/utils/colorManipulator');
let _spacing = require('material-ui/styles/spacing');
let _spacing2 = _interopRequireDefault(_spacing);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
  return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {default: obj};
}

exports.default = {
  spacing: _spacing2.default,
  fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
  borderRadius: 2,
  palette: {
    primary1Color: _colors.grey50,
    primary2Color: _colors.cyan700,
    primary3Color: _colors.grey600,
    accent1Color: _colors.lightBlue500,
    accent2Color: _colors.pinkA400,
    accent3Color: _colors.pinkA100,
    textColor: _colors.fullWhite,
    secondaryTextColor: (0, _colorManipulator.fade)(_colors.fullWhite, 0.7),
    alternateTextColor: '#303030',
    canvasColor: '#303030',
    borderColor: (0, _colorManipulator.fade)(_colors.fullWhite, 0.3),
    disabledColor: (0, _colorManipulator.fade)(_colors.fullWhite, 0.3),
    pickerHeaderColor: (0, _colorManipulator.fade)(_colors.fullWhite, 0.12),
    clockCircleColor: (0, _colorManipulator.fade)(_colors.fullWhite, 0.12)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021 and version 4.11.1, you can do this:

```
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const StyledTabs = withStyles({
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: 'orange'
  }
})(Tabs);
```

and then use StyledTabs, instead of Tabs.

Link to docs:

https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/#css

https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#shorthand

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change active tab color like this:

```js
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  sx={{
    "& .MuiTabs-indicator": {
      backgroundColor: "#F49200", // This can be a color of your choice
    },
  }}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CSS Modules, the following worked for me:

in `index.module.css` file:

```
.tabs :global(.MuiTabs-indicator) {
    background-color: #D97D54;
}
```

in `index.tsx` file:

```
import styles from "./index.module.css"

  <Tabs
    ...
    className={styles.tabs}
  >
    ...
  </Tabs>
```

Answer (score -7):

You could make a pink div that is animated with JavaScript of JQuery. It would be held inside a green div the same color as the tabs.

Comment: But it's React and Material UI. I need to know, how change this component style... If it were just a vanila JS or JQuery, then no problems. But I have no idea, how change color in this Component