# How to change active tab inkBarStyle color and thickness in React Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

See this question here:
[How to change active tab color in MUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324691/how-change-active-tab-color-in-react-material-ui)

And this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37332913/4561887

The answer they gave works:

```
<Tabs inkBarStyle={{background: 'blue'}}>...
```

But I'd also like to change the inkBarStyle to be black and thicker.
Here's the Material-UI Tabs documentation where I found the `inkBarStyle` Tabs property: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs.

Here's what I've tried. All have failed:

```
<Tabs inkBarStyle={{background: 'black'}, {background-size: 100% 300%}}>
<Tabs inkBarStyle={{background: 'black', background-size: 100% 300%}}>
<Tabs inkBarStyle={{background: 'black', height: 100px}}>
etc.
```

Also, where do I find a list of possible inkBarStyle options I can set here, and how do I set multiple options at once? Can I use any CSS property here? Ex: list: http://www.htmldog.com/references/css/properties/

I'm an embedded (microcontroller) programmer here trying to modify a GUI. Way out of my league here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect that `ink` element you'll see it's thickness is defined by it's `height`.

So you'd need to pass besides the `background` is the `height` value you want.. i.e.

```
inkBarStyle={{ background: "#000", height: "5px", marginTop: "-5px" }}
```

The `marginTop` value is needed so the ink doesn't go outside the Tab element. You can play around it here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jpnr541543
Hello.js component has the tabs related code.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean by "inspect" please? Normally in my work this would mean I get out an oscilloscope, a logic analyzer, and a multimeter--maybe even a spectrum analyzer or a microscope, but never a browser. I think what you mean is to right-click in the Chrome Browser and go to "Inspect"? You see, I'm so new to this stuff that never would have ever occurred to me as I have virtually no understanding yet of how it all works. You've been a huge help.

Comment: When I inspect it I see the marginTop is called `margin-top`. How did you know you needed to write it `marginTop` instead?

Comment: @GabrielStaples Hey, so you werere right about the inspect I mentioned. By clicking on inspect (on right-click menu) you open the devtools, and there you can check how they were styling the component: the css properties, etc..

Comment: @GabrielStaples Regarding the margin-top/marginTop question: react styling works this way, it's just the camelCase version of the css properties. Read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Answer (score 0):

The inkBarStyle solution has been deprecated.

You can now use the TabIndicatorProps to style the active indicator color & thickness with the current version of MUI (4.10.02). Docs available [here](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/).

**Here's how to do it using className: {classes}**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Tabs, Tab, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    height: "10px",
    top: "45px"
  },
  tabsWrapper: {
    height: "60px",
    background: "lightgreen"
  }
}));

const TabsIndicator = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          className={classes.tabsWrapper}
          TabIndicatorProps={{ className: classes.indicator }}
        >
          <Tab label="TEST1" value={0} />
          <Tab label="TEST2" value={1} />
          <Tab label="TEST3" value={2} />
          <Tab label="TEST4" value={3} />
        </Tabs>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default TabsIndicator;
```

indicator: {backgroundColor: ""} changes the active indicator color

indicator: {height: ""} changes the active indicator thickness

indicator: {top: ""} positions the active indicator from the top of the wrapper

tabsWrapper: {height: ""} changes the height of `<Tabs/>` . It is necessary to change this if your indicator is too thick until it is outside .

tabsWrapper: {backgroundColor: ""} changes the backgroundColor of `<Tabs/>`

You can also check out my [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-tabs-sbwch?file=/src/pages/sections/Tabs01indicator.js:0-2178) for further reference. Hope this helps!