# How to implement custom Tab indicator color in Material-UI v1

Tags: tabs, material-ui

I have MUI v1 beta 32 running on a production site, very nicely.
Time to update to v1!
So far, changes have been very simple. It's mostly been a matter of updating the import tags.

But I am running into an issue with my selected `<Tab/>` indicator.
I was using the `rootInheritSelected` style override in order to apply the color of my choice.

How to implement it in v1?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the end I found it was much simpler:

```
<Tabs
  textColor="inherit"
  fullWidth
  centered
  classes={{
    indicator: classes.indicator
  }}>
    <Tab />
    <Tab />
</Tabs>
```

and the styles:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
})
```

Comment: I really had to dig to find this. All other solutions seem to be depreciated. Glad U posted

Comment: Still works, others seem deprecated, good answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the TabIndicatorProps.

Example:

```
        <Tabs
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            this.setState({value: newValue})
          }}
          TabIndicatorProps={{
            style: {
              backgroundColor: "your_custom_color"
          },
          }}
        >
```

This allowed me to also add different indicator colors based on what tab is active